# Django Get ValidationError Message in View

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm writing my RESTful service by hand. Form and view is as below:

#### forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="E-Posta", help_text="E-postalar gerçek bir kişi olduğunuzu anlamamız için gereklidir.", min_length=3)
    username = forms.SlugField(required=True, label="Kullanıcı Adı", help_text="Kullanıcı adınız bir sefer seçilebilir. Daha sonra değiştirilemez. boşluk barındıramaz.")
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Şifre", help_text="Parolanız en az 8 karakterden oluşmalıdır.", min_length=8)
    password_validate = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Tekrar Şifre", min_length=8)
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_validate = self.cleaned_data.get("password_validate")

        if password != password_validate:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Şifreler uyuşmuyor.") # This is my error message.
```

#### views.py

```
def registration_validator(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        response = HttpResponse("", content_type="text/plain")
        response.status_code = 405
        return response

    registration_form = web_forms.RegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if registration_form.is_valid() == False:
        response = HttpResponse("", content_type="text/plain") # Here I want to return the message of ValidationError which is raised in forms.py.
        response.status_code = 400
        return response

    response = HttpResponse("", content_type=content_type)
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
```

How can I return the message of ValidationError in `views.py`?

## Environment

- django 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same as you would in the template: by accessing the `registration_form.errors` dict.

Comment: Which elements do that dictionary has? I mean, `form.errors["message"]` will work? Any documentation is okay.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors - note that `registration_form.errors.as_json()` will probably be useful for you here.